# Java Sorting logic and Identifying max of two objects

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, comparator

The requirement is to find the latest employee objects (latest date) having group number 8 with department 2 and having group number 4 within department 2. Same way group number 8 within department 1 and group number 4 in department 1. I only need the latest one object of all the above in the final list.

The comparison logic written was to sort it on the required order and retain only the required object. But I am stuck as I cannot find a way to retain single object from the sorted list. Is there anyway i can achieve it? Ignore the Comparator logic, appreciate if you can suggest any ootb way using stream or other good implementation?

```
  SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
    List<Employee> employees = new LinkedList<Employee>(Arrays.asList(
        new Employee("Emp1", df.parse("12-08-2020"),
            new EmpType("1", new Group(8))),
        new Employee("Emp2", df.parse("11-08-2020"),
            new EmpType("2", new Group(8))),
        new Employee("Emp3", df.parse("10-08-2020"),
            new EmpType("2", new Group(4))),
        new Employee("Emp4", df.parse("17-08-2020"),
            new EmpType("2", new Group(8))),
        new Employee("Emp5", df.parse("19-08-2020"),
            new EmpType("1", new Group(4)))));


    /* Sorting logic to sort by group number first then by department and then by date */
    Collections.sort(employees, new Comparator<Employee>() {
      @Override
      public int compare(Employee employee, Employee t1) {
        int val = 0;
        if (employee.getEmpType().getGroup().getNumber() < t1.getEmpType().getGroup().getNumber()) {
          val = 1;
        } else if (employee.getEmpType().getGroup().getNumber() > t1.getEmpType().getGroup()
            .getNumber()) {
          val = -1;
        } else {
          val = 0;
        }

        if (val == 0) {
          val = -(employee.getEmpType().getDepartment().compareTo(t1.getEmpType().getDepartment()));
        }
        if (val == 0) {
          val = -employee.getDate().compareTo(t1.getDate());
        }
        return val;
      }
    });
```

Comment: Do you need the lastest employee means only lastest date one ?

Comment: Thanks Rono. I am actually not looking for the max from the list. As in the original description, I need the latest one object of each condition, where group is 8 and department is 2 having latest date, then group is 4 and department 2 having latest date. Then group is 8 department 1 having latest date, group is 4 department 1 having latest date.

Comment: Do you need the latest one for each condition separately  ? or combinely only one?

Comment: That's right Rono, need latest one of each condition in the same final list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Collectors.toMap` of Stream API to map by `EmpType` and get the latest date for each group having the same `EmpType` using `BinaryOperator.maxBy` as values. Then get the values of map in new `ArrayList`. Here map by `EmpType` because it contains group number and department and you need proper equals and hashcode implementation for `EmpType`.

```
List<Employee> res = new ArrayList(employees.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getEmpType, Function.identity(),
        BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getDate)))).values());
```

or you can create pair of group number and department like `new  AbstractMap.SimpleEntry(e.getEmpType().getDepartment(), e.getEmpType().getGroup().getNumber())` as key instead of `EmpType` then don't need equals and hashcode implementation

```
List<Employee> res = new ArrayList(employees.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                         e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry(e.getEmpType().getDepartment(),
                                                  e.getEmpType().getGroup().getNumber()),
                                  Function.identity(),
                        BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getDate))))
        .values());
```

Comment: Excellent approach! i think the abstract map implementation does it, and looks neat as well. Thanks much Rono! I think I would go for this.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of sorting, you could use [`Collections.max`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max-java.util.Collection-java.util.Comparator-) with the same `Comparator` you've implemented.

**EDIT to address the discussion in the comments:**
If I understand the data structure correctly, `EmpType` encapsulates the unique combination we want to find the "latest" employee for. Assuming it has a proper implementation of the  `equals(Object)` and `hashCode()` methods, you could stream the list and collect it to a map from the `EmpType` to the latest employee:

```java
Map<EmpType, Employee> latestEmployees =
    employees.stream()
             .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                          Employee::getEmpType,
                          Function.identity(),
                          BinaryOperator.maxBy(
                              Comparator.comparing(Employee::getDate))));
```

Comment: Thanks Mureinik. I am actually not looking for the max from the list. As in the original description, I need the latest one object of each condition, where group is 8 and department is 2 having latest date, then group is 4 and department 2 having latest date. Then group is 8 department 1 having latest date, group is 4 department 1 having latest date.

Comment: @vipinev Are those four arbitrary classifications, or do you want to find the latest employee per unique combination of group and department?

Comment: So those are not arbitrary. That's right. Need the latest employee (date) per unique combination of group and department.

Comment: Thanks much. I think this work with the equals implementation based on department and group number. Really appreciate for familiarising the concept.

Answer (score 1):

I find it quite messy to mix the business logic inside the sort function.

Why not just sort the Employees descendingly accoring to their date and parse through the resulting array untill your conditions are met for the first time?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I could that, but would require a lots of conditional logic? So was interested to know if there is any neat implementation I could follow?

Comment: It would reduce the sorting function to a one-liner, and then you would just have to write a foreach with an if (with your long condition) and a break inside. Sorting is something general, and a sorting function must respect some conditions such as: if `a < b` and `b < c`, then `a < c`. Mixing business logic inside such a function may break these rules and result in a faulty implementation.